# asp.net mvc html.renderaction() will generate full HTML document

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would be thankful if anyone could answer me the following:

- I would like to include a partial view into a view.
- The data provided by the partial view is independent from the (main) view.

So maybe I have two controller actions:

```
Public Class MyController

    Public Function GetMainView() As ActionResult
       Return View()
    End Function 'generates (main) view

    Public Function GetPartialView(ByVal myParameter As Integer) As ActionResult
       ViewBag.MyValue = "foo"
       If (myParameter = 101) Then
          ViewBag.MyValue = "bar"
       End If
       Return View()
    End Function 'generates partial view

End Class ' MyController
```

When in the main view I could then write

```
@Code
   Html.RenderAction("GetPartialView", New With {.myParameter = 101})
End Code
```

Or

```
Html.Action("GetPartialView", New With {.myParameter = 101})
```

Problem is, this will generate a full HTML document (with html and body tags and all that...) INSIDE the original HTML document, which is all but valid code.
:-(

If on the other hand I try

```
@Code
   Html.RenderPartial("GetPartialView", New With {.myParameter = 101})
End Code
```

Or

```
Html.Partial("GetPartialView", New With {.myParameter = 101})
```

The partial view is rendered correctly - BUT the parameter I pass is ignored (the method is not even entered...), so that ViewBag.MyValue will yield "foo".
:-(

Is there a way to overcome this problem aside from dynamically loading the partial view via AJAX?

Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a PartialView:

```
Public Class MyController

    Public Function GetMainView() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function 'generates (main) view

    Public Function GetPartialView(ByVal myParameter As Integer) As ActionResult
        ViewBag.MyValue = "foo"
        If (myParameter = 101) Then
            ViewBag.MyValue = "bar"
        End If
        Return PartialView()  <<--
     End Function 'generates partial view

End Class ' MyController
```

You can also explicitly tell the name of your partial view and pass its view model, like:

```
Return PartialView("partial view name", model)
```